# concatenate all items from two lists in Python

Tags: python

I want to produce a list of possible websites from two lists:

```
strings = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
tlds = ["com', "net", "org"]
```

to produce the following output:

```
string1.com  
string1.net  
string1.org  
string2.com  
string2.net  
string2.org
```

I've got to this:

```
for i in strings:
    print i + tlds[0:]
```

But I can't concatenate str and list objects.  How can I join these?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please indent code by highlighting it and clicking the `{ }` button.  There's never a need to put `<br>` elements in the post.  Either a blank line in between, or two spaces at the end of a line will create a paragraph/line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very simple way to write this is the same as in most other languages.

```
for s in strings:
    for t in tlds:
        print s + '.' + t
```

Comment: wow, that is simple, and I understand exactly what it's doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

`itertools.product` is designed for this purpose.

```
url_tuples = itertools.product(strings, tlds)
urls = ['.'.join(url_tuple) for url_tuple in url_tuples]
print(urls)
```

Comment: Would be fun if `*` worked on lists so that you could just do `['.'.join(t) for t in strings * tlds]` or the like. :-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, You could write a class that extends `list`, and implement any operator you like :-)

Answer (score 7):

A (nested) list comprehension would be another alternative:

```
[s + '.' + tld for s in strings for tld in tlds]
```

Answer (score 5):

The `itertools` module provides a function that does this.

```
from itertools import product
urls = [".".join(elem) for elem in product(strings, tlds)]
```

The `urls` variable now holds this list:

```
['string1.com',
 'string1.net',
 'string1.org',
 'string2.com',
 'string2.net',
 'string2.org',
 'string3.com',
 'string3.net',
 'string3.org']
```

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Neither did you add information nor did you improve readability... Congrats!

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  Users unfamiliar with iPython would have had a difficult time reading that.  But, it's your answer, so I'll rollback the edit if you wish.

Comment: Actually you have a point here. The `In [x]`, `Out [y]` stuff might be confusing to some people. Replacing those by `>>>` would have been sufficient in my eyes though...